# How to get the specific position of inline elements' inline box and content area in css with some tools, for example, chrome dev tools?

Tags: css, web, frontend

I want to get the specific position of inline elements' inline box and content area in css, as shown in the following picture.  How can I do that?
[image]
This figure is from *CSS: The Definitive Guide*, 4th edition.

I tried to use chrome dev tools. But it didn't meet my requirements.

Update: with the suggestions from @Temani, I can get the position by adding background color. So I only have to make sure the position of *inline box* of `<p>` and `<strong>` element.

```css
p {
  background: red;
}
strong {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:12px;">
which is <strong style="font-size:24px;">strongly emphasized</strong> and which is 
</p>
```

Comment: apply background color to the element in order to hightlight the content area

Answer (score 0):

If the position of the question is offset, it can be obtained with javascript.

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>header</div>
  <span id="inline-box">which is <span id="content-area" style="font-size: 30px">strongly emphasized</span> and which
    is</span>
  <div>footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
$('#inline-box').offset().top
$('#inline-box').offset().left
$('#content-area').offset().top
$('#content-area').offset().left
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I want to know the position of inline box. Do you know *inline box*: For nonplaced elements, the height of the inline box of an element will be exactly equal to the value for line-height.

Comment: @A.Chao sorry, I can't understand what you want. If you need position in either "Block-Level Elements" or "Inline Elements", you can get it with `$('#inline-box').offset()` or `$('#inline-box').position()`. If you want to get area size of an element, place an empty element to end of the content-area and calculate `$('#empty-element').position().left - $('#content-area').position().left`.

Answer (score -1):

You're right. You can check this position in chrome dev tool. For your brouser "content-area" for this element has line-height: 16px; But it could be other for other brouser if you woudn't use [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or [reset](https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6) styles. You should personal control this element if it's important for you. Give him a class for example.